# Print python script to a file

Tags: python, html, python-3.x

Hi Im a newbie about python,

I have 2000 list of company that I want to share in my website.
I was able to import my csv file, using python script.
This is my code:

```
import csv

with open('test.csv', 'r') as csvfile:
   r = csv.reader(csvfile, delimiter=',')
   for row in r:
       print (row)
```

Will you help me on how can I print this to a file?

Thanks!

Comment: Just use 'open' to open a file and write it

Comment: What format do you want it to be written in

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
import csv

with open('test.csv', 'r') as csvfile:
   r = csv.reader(csvfile, delimiter=',')
   with open(file_path,"w") as text_file:
       for row in r:
           text_file.write(row+"\n")
```

Printing each row in separate files generated with an increment number

```
  with open('test.csv', 'r') as csvfile:
       r = csv.reader(csvfile, delimiter=',')
       cnt=0
       for row in r:
           cnt+=1
           file_path="text_file %s.txt" % (str(cnt),)
           with open(file_path,"w") as text_file:               
               text_file.write(row+"\n")
```

Comment: Thanks for sharing!

Comment: Do you have tips on how to print each row into separate files (txt)

Comment: Thank you. This code works, I will definitely study and learn each line of this.Is it possible if you can help me to understand the code.

Comment: Since I was able to print each line to text file. I want to make the first column of my csv file as header of each row. then convert it to html, do you have any tutorial that you recommend?

Comment: It is possible...I think if you ask another question with this requirement you will get good anwsers. ensure you include some text in your csv file and what you would like to achieve....

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42958175/python-read-csv-file-and-print-write-each-rowkeep-header-to-html-file?noredirect=1#comment73011679_42958175

Answer (score 1):

I like repzero's answer, but rows need to be converted to str()

```
import csv  ##  import comma separated value module
```

open test.csv in readonly mode as a variable csvfile

```
with open('test.csv', 'r') as csvfile:
```

set the variable csvdata to all the data read from csvfile,
splitting everytime it finds a comma

```
    csvdata = csv.reader(csvfile, delimiter=',')
```

open test.txt in write mode as a variable text_file

```
    with open(test.txt, 'w') as text_file:
```

iterate through every row of the csv data

```
        for row in csvdata:
```

convert the row of data into a string of text,
and write it to the file, followed by a newline

```
            text_file.write(str(row) + '\n')
```

Comment: Hi I was able to run the script. Can you help to understand the process, each line of the code?

Comment: Do you have tips on how to print each row into separate files (txt)

Answer (score 0):

Create a [file object](https://docs.python.org/3/glossary.html#term-file-object) using [`open()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#open), write to it, then close it.

```
file = open("path/to/file.txt", "w+")
for row in r:        
    file.write(row)
file.close()
```

Comment: Thanks for sharing!

Answer (score 0):

Differ from the other answers, you can actually "print" directly to a file using the same keyword `print`. By rerouting the file method:

```
import csv

with open('test.csv') as csvfile, open("yourfilepath.txt", "w") as txtfile:
   r = csv.reader(csvfile, delimiter=',')
   for row in r:
       print (row, file = txtfile)
```

Comment: Thanks for sharing!