# PYTHON: Read Csv file and print/write each row(keep header) to HTML File

Tags: python, html, csv

I was able to generate html file per row.

my current output for "text_file 1.html" is the header: `['ID', 'Name', 'Type', '3 Year Funds Offered', '3 Year Funds Sold', 'Est. Most Recent Fund Date', 'Investor Location', 'Investor City', 'Investor State', 'Investor Country', 'Portfolio Size', 'Number of Deals', 'Website', 'Average Growth Score']`

**But I want to customize the table/data and keep the Header for each data from csv.**

Here's my sample code:

```
import csv

    with open('test.csv', 'r') as csvfile:
           r = csv.reader(csvfile, delimiter=',')
           cnt=0
           for row in r:
               cnt+=1
               file_path="text_file %s.html" % (str(cnt),)
               with open(file_path,"w") as text_file:               
                   text_file.write(str(row)+"\n")`enter code here`
```

Do you have any tips so I can run this correctly? Thanks!

Comment: Can you edit your question to show the expected output?  Are you trying to write each row to a separate file, or maybe you want to create an HTML table in a single file?

Comment: I misread for my last comment. Keeping with your current code, define something like `my_headers = ['ID', 'Name', 'Type', '3 Year Funds Offered', '3 Year Funds Sold',...]` before `with open('test.csv', 'r') as csvfile:` and then under `with open(file_path,"w") as text_file:` have another line that writes your headers like `text_file.write(','.join(item for item in my_headers)+"\n")`. And then look at [`pandas to_html`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.to_html.html) and use that instead :)

Comment: Actually my expected output is just a regular table with header and 1 row below. I have 2000 rows from my csv file. I was able to generate html each row already using my current py code.

Comment: Will you give me your sample code for this?